# TF Service's Hosted Build Controller running msbuildcommunitytasks: "Could not find git.exe."

Tags: git, msbuild, azure-devops, msbuildcommunitytasks

I am using MSBuildCommunityTasks to retrieve the git commit hash at build time:

```
<GitVersion LocalPath="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)">
  <Output TaskParameter="CommitHash" PropertyName="GitRevision" />
</GitVersion>
```

MSBUILD executes this task as expected on my local machine but fails on when Team Foundation Service's Hosted Build Controller executes it:

```
SalesApplication.Versioning.csproj (81): The "GitVersion" task failed unexpectedly.
System.Exception: Could not find git.exe.  Looked in PATH locations and various common folders inside Program Files.
```

Apparently the hosted build controllers employed by TFService do not afford direct access to git.exe according to the list of installed packages: http://listofsoftwareontfshostedbuildserver.azurewebsites.net/

**How can MSBUILD retrieve git commit information on the hosted build controller?**

Comment: You could check in the Git binaries and reference them from your source control mapping.

Comment: Good suggestion! I did just this; unfortunately in the process I found an issue within MSBuild community tasks in which GitVersion's LocalPath is ignored : https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks/issues/100 ; fixed the issue on a local fork and initiated a pull request with the fix.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://forum.team-mediaportal.com/threads/onlinevideos-2-1-0-0-2015-09-26.130171/page-17) actually helped.
I basically had to reninstall Git with the option

**Use Git from the Windows Command Prompt**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This was due to MSBuild failed to locate git.exe location (ie. C:\Program Files\Git\bin). You can check whether your java.library.path (Manage Jenkins > System Info) contains git path or not if not you need to add git location to your Path variable then reboot your server to take effect. Hope this help.

**In Windows environment, java.library.path is same with PATH variable.